# Post Facebook Comment with Link Preview via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, comments

Facebook recently added link previews to user comments.

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/07/21/facebook-comment-previews/

My question: is there a way to display this link preview using any of the Facebook APIs and publish_stream permission? (Graph, rest, etc)?

I've tried posting a URL in the body of a comment using the Graph API /comments endpoint, but no link preview is shown.

The feature might still be too immature to allow this, but I'm wondering if any one has tried it and got it to work in some way.

Comment: Check this question. Similar one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237525/facebook-graph-api-posting-links-thumbnail-not-displaying/9271792#9271792

Comment: I think the difference here is that I wanted to do it in the comment via the API, not via a post.

Comment: @ricosrealm, did you come up with a solution?

Comment: no unfortunately... seems like an open issue... viewed 612 times.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just post a comment (for example) with youtube video and it will transfer to embed one

Comment: Have you tested via the Graph API?  I tried this but it didn't post the preview, just the link.